# Google Map icon colour change by value from Fusion Table

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have a website at http://www.gfmap.com and it shows gluten-free restaurants, shops, bakeries, etc. It is run off a Fusion Table with more than 20,000 items.

I want to know if I can change the Google Map icon colour based on the category (restaurant, etc)

Here's the code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
 var initialLocation; 
 var companyLocale = new google.maps.LatLng(-33.869629, 151.206955); 
 var localArray = [companyLocale]; 
 var noGeo = new google.maps.LatLng(51.506325, -0.127144);        
 var map;    
 var layerl0;    
 function initialize() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('themap'),
     {
        zoom: 12 
     });
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        browserSupportFlag = true;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        initialLocation = new     google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
        handleNoGeolocation(browserSupportFlag);
       });
    }else {
       handleNoGeolocation();
    }
function handleNoGeolocation() {
  initialLocation = noGeo;
  localArray.unshift(initialLocation);
  map.setCenter(initialLocation);
}
    var style = [
    {
      featureType: 'administrative.land_parcel',
      elementType: 'all',
      stylers: [
        { visibility: 'off' }
      ]
    }
  ];

    var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(style, {
      map: map,
      name: 'Styled Map'
    });
  map.mapTypes.set('map-style', styledMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId('map-style');
  layerl0 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: "'location'",
      from: 4015038
    },
    map: map
  });
}
function changeMapl0() {
  var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string-l0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  layerl0.setOptions({
    query: {
      select: "'location'",
      from: 4015038,
      where: "'Type' = '" + searchString + "'"
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
function ga() {
  var address = document.getElementById('q').value;
  if (address != ''){
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address + ' AU'}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            if (results[0].geometry.location_type == google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.APPROXIMATE){
              map.setZoom(12);
            } else {map.setZoom(12);}
          }
          else {alert("Sorry, we can't find that place using Google.");}
        });

  }
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-31494612-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

</script>
```

I think the answer is related to this post [Custom Google Map Icon If Value >=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065604/custom-google-map-icon-if-value-1) but I cannot make it work. I don't know JavaScript and have really just hacked this website together best I can.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Matt

Comment: You should reformat your code block, it's very hard to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of predefined markers you can use for fusionTables(and there is no way to apply other markers than them).

You'll find them here: [**https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1BDnT5U1Spyaes0Nj3DXciJKa_tuu7CzNRXWdVA**](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1BDnT5U1Spyaes0Nj3DXciJKa_tuu7CzNRXWdVA) 
(click on visualize->map to see them)

You may use them for the styling of the Layer, e.g.:

```
styles:[{
            where: "Type='Restaurant'",
            markerOptions: {iconName: "rec_dining"}
          }]
```

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/5MuL4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/5MuL4/)

Comment: Or you can use the FusionTables User Interface to create a new column and assign them there.

Comment: Wouldn't  that  be redundant when he only want's to have markers based on the category?

Comment: Depends on how may "categories" there are.  If there are more than 5 (which there aren't in this case), the dynamic styling solution won't work.

Comment: Thanks all so much. The 'styles' looks like it may be the go. I will try it tonight when the kids go to bed! Where would I put the command in the maps code I have above or does it not matter? And thanks SO much for the example. I should be fine with that. you are a star, Dr Molle.

Comment: When you look at the linked fiddle you must take the object used as argument for `new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer()` and use it in your code as argument for `layerl0.setOptions()`

Comment: OK, am trying to make that work. Thanks again. Am using the excellent jsfiddle. Have forked it to http://jsfiddle.net/mattmartel/bYgWu/1/  and have put web page at http://jsfiddle.net/mattmartel/a8YyQ/1/ I will see how I go.

Comment: Dr Molle, Thanks again for your help. I just don't have the Javascript skills (will learn when I find a spare lifetime) but I downloaded the Fusion table as a csv and then used Excel to do all the marker styles. Have now uploaded and I am currently waiting for 20,000 locations to geocode. In the end, it was my fear of js vs my fear of Excel.

Comment: next time, before you intend to download the table to modify it with excel, keep in  mind that it's a database-table. You can update it without downloading  by using SQL-like queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically request icon images from the [Google charts api](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html#pins)  with the urls:

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|FE7569
```

Which looks like this: [image] the image is **21x43** pixels and the pin tip is at position **(10, 34)**

And you'll also want a separate shadow image (so that it doesn't overlap nearby icons):

```
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow
```

Which looks like this: [image] the image is **40x37** pixels and the pin tip is at position **(12, 35)**

When you construct your [MarkerImage](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#MarkerImage) you need to set the size and anchor points accordingly:

```
    var pinColor = "FE7569";
    var pinImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=%E2%80%A2|" + pinColor,
        new google.maps.Size(21, 34),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(10, 34));
    var pinShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_shadow",
        new google.maps.Size(40, 37),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(12, 35));
```

You can then add the marker to your map with:

```
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0), 
                map: map,
                icon: pinImage,
                shadow: pinShadow
            });
```

Simply replace "FE7569" with the color code you're after.

Comment: did you read that we talk about fusionTables, how would you apply the marker there?